# SecureRandom, all different tokens

Tags: java, token

I was wondering about the fiability of `SecureRandom`.

I'm generating a token (which is sometimes used as an identifier) like that :

```
public String createAccessToken() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    String token = bytes.toString();
    return token.substring(3);
}
```

And my question is : Is there a chance, even completely tiny, that 2 completely equals tokens are generated ? (maybe by calling this method twice at the same exact moment or maybe through time)

If not, what can I add to this method so there is no more fault ?

PS : Sorry in advance for my English

Comment: If you want guaranteed unique tokens you could try an `UUID` instead.

Comment: "Is there a chance, even completely tiny, that 2 completely equals tokens are generated" Yes, it's random.

Comment: Actually it's "pseudo-random". Oh and if I add a "timestamp" in it, can it prevent more ?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use `UUID.randomUUID()`.

Comment: I was looking into it at the instant ^^ Thanks

Comment: And if you have something horribly expensive like a `SecureRandom`, seriously consider saving it rather than recreating it in each method call.

Comment: It is saved in a database. But I'm going with the UUID idea (event if the generated url becomes longer)